# Database commit and rollback depends on connections?

Tags: php, mysql, database

Consider I have a PHP website, which simply connect to the DB with a Static Connection and make multiple transactions, commit, rollback if necessary.

**Considering there is simultaneous visitors.** 
-User A is making 3 transactions (Started First) 
-User B is making 3 transactions (Started Second)

Now User B is completed and the system commits the transaction but User A is still not committed the transactions.

Now, User A made a mistake and want to rollback the transactions. Is that possible ?

Can someone explain ?

Comment: Do you want to rollback the committed transaction which is done by User B if User A makes some mistake and vice versa?

Comment: If user A starts a transaction and doesn't complete it, user B won't be able to secure a lock on that table and therefore won't be able to do anything until user A is finished.

Comment: Thank you @JeffUK. So Static connection is not a best practice ? do we need to create a connection for each user ? what if it was a highly scalable application ?

Comment: @Jana there is no need to create a separate connection for each user. The transaction default behavior is the same as what you need.